# Associate rig to similar character

Tags: rigging, shrinkwrap

I made a rig for a low poly character. During the process, I accidentally deleted the original character. The low poly character had a shrinkwrap (to the high poly character) and a multiresolution modifier, trying to not loose detail.
Now, I have 1 blender file with the correct rig and the low poly character, and 1 blender file with the original character, without rig.
I tried to copy and paste things from one project to another, but I doesn't work. I tried to copy the high poly and the low poly at the same position and apply a Shrinkwrap modifier, but it doesn't work.
I'm desperated, I need to have done this for tomorrow.
Please help me. I would upload the blender files but I don't know how to do it So if you want to help, please tell me how can I upload the blender files and I will send them to you if you don't mind to take a look.

Comment: Put the blend files on blend-exchange.com then edit your post to add the link

Comment: Once you have rig and character together in the same file, you need to parent  the mesh object to the armature object. Did you do that?
To do this, select the mesh object, then shift-select the armature object. Press Ctrl + P to bring up the Parent menu, then select Armature Deform > With Automatic Weights